Counting the number of pulses from a sound card using python (for a geiger counter project)
I am currently building a diy geiger counter.
Each pulse generated by the geiger counter is send to a sound card which is connected to my pc.
I want to write a python program which will tell me the number of pulses registered every second.(PPS)
The pulses in sound recorder
Is there a library in python which can be used?
please note that are the pulses are not exactly the same. And there is a fair bit of noise in the input.
-best regards

You have to check if the signal is higher than a given threshold ( threshold = background noise). Knowing the sample rate, you can define a "window" of samples to check
